# Como implementar um player de vídeo com opções de qualidade para reprodução online?

Tags: javascript, html5, biblioteca, reprodutor-de-video

Alguém sabe de alguma biblioteca ou outra forma de reproduzir os vídeos do meu servidor com controle de qualidade para evitar carregamento lento, estilo o do youtube, para que o usuário selecione a resolução (por exemplo).

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe o [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js), uma biblioteca open-source com boa popularidade no GitHub, utilizada em mais de 400,000 websites, segundo a própria página.

Há também o [JW Player](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer), o mais popular player embarcado do mundo, segundo a própria página.

Outras opções para tecnologias de mídia podem ser vistas [neste site de estatísticas](https://trends.builtwith.com/media).